# How to autoIncrement values and save them in a List in Android

Tags: android, listview, auto-increment

I want to save every scanned item in a list with a name "Draft"+serial Number,

> example: when 1st item is selected it will be saved as Draft1, when
>   2nd item is scanned it will be saved as Draft2 and so on..

I tried this with sharedPrefrences but it doesn't help me.
what else approach should I go for?

Here's my code:

```
btn_save_draft.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try{
                int countt = 0;

            if (!list.isEmpty()) {

            if(arrayAdapter==null || arrayAdapter.getCount()==0){

                if(editor!=null){
                    System.out.println("==clear SharedPref data==");
                   sPrefs.edit().clear().commit();

                }

            }

                editor = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                        int defaultValue =   
getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("count_key",countt);
                        System.out.println("===def==="+defaultValue);
                             ++defaultValue;


getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).edit().putInt("count_key",defaultValue)
.commit();
                            countt = 
getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE).getInt("count_key",countt);

                showSaveDraftDialog(countt);
}else {
                Toast.makeText(mActivity, "Try again",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

Comment: instead of using shared preference use local database .

Comment: Can you post some code?

Comment: Sheena, `I tried this with sharedPrefrences but it doesn't help me` what problem getting using sharedPrefrences?

Comment: I'm not able to reset my Sharedprefrences  when there's no item in the list. and secondly suppose there are 3 items in the list and I open Draft2, modify that and again save it in the list it should be saved as Draft2 but it saves as Draft4. I don't know how to achieve this through SharedPref.

Answer (score 0):

When ever you need to save the name, you can do something like:

```
item.setName("draft "+i++);
```

where `i` is a static global variable and `item` is the type of object you need to put in `Draft`. Create a separate class for that object, define a parameter called `name` and generate its getter and setter methods. Hope it might help.